# Delete all files and sub directories but keep main directory

Tags: powershell

I have a folder whose entire entire contents I want to delete, but I want to keep the actual folder. I have tried this:

```
function deleteFiles {
  # The parameter. 
  param([string]$sourceDir) 

  # Move the files
  Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

  #Delete empty directories
  Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName) -eq $null
  } | Remove-Item 
}
```

However as one of the subdirectories has its own sub directories they aren't deleted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
Remove-Item -Path "$sourceDir\*" -Recurse
```

Comment: I zip the contents of the folder to a different location then want to delete the old one - this seems to be causing odd behaviour that the zipped folders are missing information - will check logs and get back.

Comment: If your zip operation runs asynchronously it may simply not be completed when you run `Remove-Item`, thus causing items to be missing in the zip file. That would be a different question, though.

Comment: When I use your sample, it removes the parent directory too.  Maybe newer versions of powershell do this?  I am using 5.1

Comment: @JohnDyer Maybe try doing `Set-Location '$sourceDir'` followed by `Remove-Item -Recurse`.

Comment: Perfect answer here.